# Guidance on writing a Foundry Test for a deploy script! (Lesson 9: Raffle contract)

Tags: solidity, contract-deployment, testing, unittesting, foundry

I am following the new foundry course by Patrick and was wondering if I could get tips on how to test the deploy script - https://github.com/Cyfrin/foundry-smart-contract-lottery-f23/blob/main/script/DeployRaffle.s.sol

I am unable to brainstorm ideas on how the testing should happen:

```
contract DeployRaffleTest is Test {
    uint256 entranceFee;
    uint256 interval;
    address vrfCoordinator;
    bytes32 gasLane;
    uint64 subscriptionId; //either get this from UI or make yourself
    uint32 callbackGasLimit;
    address link;
    uint256 deployerKey;
    HelperConfig helperConfig = new HelperConfig();

    function setUp() public {
        (
            entranceFee,
            interval,
            vrfCoordinator,
            gasLane,
            subscriptionId,
            callbackGasLimit,
            ,
            deployerKey
        ) = helperConfig.activeNetworkConfig();
    }

    Raffle deployedRaffle;

    //     new Raffle(
    //         entranceFee,
    //         interval,
    //         vrfCoordinator,
    //         gasLane,
    //         subscriptionId,
    //         callbackGasLimit
    //     );

    function testDeployRaffleReturnValuesAreNotNull() public {
        DeployRaffle deployer = new DeployRaffle();
        (deployedRaffle, helperConfig) = deployer.run();

        assert(address(deployedRaffle) != address(0));
        assert(address(helperConfig) != address(0));
    }
}
```

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `forge test` to run all the tests quickly.

To test particular file you can use `forge test ../path`

To fork a network you can use:-
`forge test --rpc-url url-here`